Scrolling to the bottom of a div element using Selenium (Python)
I want to scroll a particular div element in a website until it reaches its bottom.
Say i have this html:
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>list1</li>
        <li>list2</li>
        <li>list3</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <li>previous</li>
        <li>current</li>
        <li>next</li>
    </ol>

</div>

Now the <ol> element is out of my viewport at the bottom of the page and in the entire page, the div listed above is the only scrollable element. How do I scroll to the bottom of this so I can have <ol> in my viewport and i could interact with it using selenium? Like using .click(). I cannot juts scroll to the bottom of the page as only the div is scrollable and trying to scroll anywhere else does nothing.
Looking at previous StackOverflow threads I tried to locate the div and then scroll along it using javascript like so:
div = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div")
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', div)

I hoped this was would scroll the div to the <ol> list and i could interact with it. Unfortunately this did not do anything and i still got a NoSuchElementException error.

You said you wanted to scroll to the OL but your locator finds a DIV.

@JeffC
yes I'm not sure how exactly all of this works, since OL exists in the div, shouldnt the div be scrolled? After all its the div that is scrollable and not the list.

The JS you are calling doesn't scroll an element with a scrollbar, it scrolls the entire page down to the element you provided. If you want to scroll to the OL, you pass in the OL and it will scroll to it. You should probably test it out in the dev console to better understand how it works.

Looking at the HTML code of the page provided in the comments, the <ol> tag is enclosed in the <nav> tags with id of paging. You can use the #paging CSS selector to get to these elements.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.homes.com/san-francisco-ca/homes-for-rent/1-to-5-bedroom/?price-max=3000")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
nav_tag = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#paging")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", nav_tag)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.quit()


I tried it but no scrolling. This is the page I'm trying to scroll in

I've changed the answer to provide the code to scroll to the <nav> element containing the pagination links.

thanks for telling me about that, I've accepted your answer.
